# Filter multiple records on right table into 1 record of left table

Tags: mysql, join

So I have a translations table which holds various representations of a place name. I join this table on the `placeId`, where this table serves as the right side (the left side contains info about the `place`).

However, joining on placeId results in possibly more translations, see table below. The contents of preferredName/shortName/historicName are all 0 or 1. There is no rule though that each translation should have at least 1 record with `preferredName=1`.

So what I end up with is: how can I select only 1 of these translations, in particular:

- if record exists with `preferredName=1`: use this
- else if record exists with `shortName=1`: use this
- else if neither is true (so both are 0) then pick that record

.

```
+---------------+---------+------------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+
| translationId | placeId |  alternateName   | preferredName | shortName | historicName |
+---------------+---------+------------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+
|          4832 |     554 | 'New York'       |             1 |         0 |            0 |
|          4833 |     554 | 'NY'             |             0 |         1 |            0 |
|          4834 |     554 | 'New York City'  |             0 |         0 |            0 |
+---------------+---------+------------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+
```

Any clue? It basically boils down to filtering multiple matches on the right table to 1 record on the left table.

Comment: Order by "preferredName" and "ShortName", and then, pick the first result ;)

Comment: how would you do this when you are matching 10 places to these translations; i want to return 10 records in this case (with each record having the appropriate translation as a field)

Comment: You can make your join on a subrequest 'select ... from ... order by ...' and maybe 'limit 1'

Comment: i just add an answer to show you the request on wich you need to join ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could join 3 times with different conditions and COALESCE the results:

```
select 
a.*,
coalesce(name1.alternateName, name2.alternateName, name3.alternateName) as alternateName
from _table1_ as a
left join _table2_ as name1 on (a.placeId = name1.placeId and name1.preferredName=1)
left join _table2_ as name2 on (a.placeId = name2.placeId and name2.shortName=1)
left join _table2_ as name3 on (a.placeId = name3.placeId and name3.preferredName=0 and name3.shortName=0)
group by a.placeId
```

Comment: i will try this out in a moment; just 1 thing: the pairs 1-1, 1-0, 0-1 and 0-0 can all exist for preferredName/shortName (pairs can even exist double, but then we can just take either).

So it should return 1-1 before 1-0, 1-0 before 0-1, and 0-1 before 0-0

Answer (score 0):

Following my previous comment, you can make your JOIN request on a subrequest.

try this :

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE placeId = 554 ORDER BY preferredName DESC, shortName DESC;
```

it will order results exactly as you want, with your preferrence. Juste add a limit 1 ant you are right !

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE placeId = 554 ORDER BY preferredName DESC, shortName DESC LIMIT 1;
```

so, just add you first part of request and make your join on this ;)

EDIT : the following is relative to a comment

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM alternatename
     WHERE isoLanguage="NL" AND geonameid = a1.geonameid
     ORDER BY isPreferredName DESC, isShortName DESC
     LIMIT 1
     )
  AS alternate10
ON
  alternate10.geonameid = a1.geonameid
```

Comment: hmm yes this seems to solve the problem; however: im using a pretty large dataset, and i've just built this subquery into my main query and it added 13 seconds to the execution time.

Comment: If you want we try to optimise your request, can you show us your main request ? This request is pretty quick, so i think we need to work then on your main, and maybe find wich index can be usefull in your case.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/tqG0N5ds

that is the general idea. Note: the Full Text Search (MATCH/AGAINST) is not the culprit. Query performs in 50ms or so when not doing subqueries

Comment: I see 2 possible way to improve it : 1 => add the g.geonameid condition inside the wehre in the subrequest. So, the order by will work on a really small amount of data. (same for you a1 or a2) "WHERE isoLanguage="NL" and geonameid = g.geonameid"

Comment: i think i will go with a join solution; i've fiddled around a bit with the subqueries and they dont seem to be optimized enough by mysql.

sadly the dataset im working with isnt the most abstract one, so i cannot circumvent having to join the same table 3 times. 3 subqueries in this case will hurt performance

Comment: Did you try to add the geonameid condition inside the subrequest ? it should be really quick... And so, you will join 3 times, but on 3 small dataset which will already contain all you need ;)
I edit my answezr to add the sample i thoiin you should try.

Comment: i dont believe i am able to use `WHERE geonameid = g.geonameid` in the subquery. It doesnt recognize the parent query